# How to convert character to date with two different types of date formats in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime

I have a huge dataset with over 2 million obs and all column's classes are character type. I need to convert one of them to date format dd/mm/yyyy, but the dates are written like this:

```
dates <- c("2022-04-08", "26/01/2021", "14/07/2021", "2021-12-27")
```

I've already tried some explanations I found in other posts but none of them seemed to work for me. One groupe of dates always turns into NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like:

```r
format_ymd  <- as.Date(dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
format_dmy  <- as.Date(dates, format = "%d/%m/%Y")
as.Date(ifelse(is.na(format_ymd), format_dmy, format_ymd), origin = "1970-01-01")
# [1] "2022-04-08" "2021-01-26" "2021-07-14" "2021-12-27"
```

Answer (score 3):

**1) Base R** Use as.Date with the format vector shown. No packages are used.

```
as.Date(dates, format = ifelse(grepl("/", dates), "%d/%m/%Y", "%Y-%m-%d"))
## [1] "2022-04-08" "2021-01-26" "2021-07-14" "2021-12-27"
```

**2) Base R - 2** Another approach is to convert the dd/mm/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd and then just use as.Date.  No packages are used.

```
as.Date(sub("(..)/(..)/(....)", "\\3-\\2-\\1", dates))
## [1] "2022-04-08" "2021-01-26" "2021-07-14" "2021-12-27"
```

**3) lubridate**  With lubridate use parse_date_time and then convert that to Date class.

```
library(lubridate)

as.Date(parse_date_time(dates, c("ymd", "dmy")))
## [1] "2022-04-08" "2021-01-26" "2021-07-14" "2021-12-27"
```

**4) coalesce**  We can use coalesce in dplyr.  It takes the first non-NA it finds.

```
library(dplyr)

coalesce(as.Date(dates), as.Date(dates, "%d/%m/%Y"))
## [1] "2022-04-08" "2021-01-26" "2021-07-14" "2021-12-27"
```

Answer (score 2):

Similar to SamR's approach

```
data.table::fifelse(
  grepl("^\\d{4}", dates),
  as.Date(dates,"%Y-%m-%d"),
  as.Date(dates, "%d/%m/%Y")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

With the clock package, you can supply multiple `format`s to `date_parse()` and it will try them in order. It is nice for cases like this where the formats are drastically different.

```r
library(clock)

dates <- c("2022-04-08", "26/01/2021", "14/07/2021", "2021-12-27")

# Tries each `format` in order. Stops on first success.
date_parse(
  dates,
  format = c("%Y-%m-%d", "%d/%m/%Y")
)
#> [1] "2022-04-08" "2021-01-26" "2021-07-14" "2021-12-27"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>