# Convert "xx-xxx-xxxx" to date in R

Tags: r, date

I want to convert strings such as `"19-SEP-2022"` to date. Is there any available function in R? Thank you.

Comment: `as.Date("19-SEP-2022","%d-%b-%Y")`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert character to date with two different types of date formats in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71843108/how-to-convert-character-to-date-with-two-different-types-of-date-formats-in-r)

Comment: @Limey, that's not quite a duplicate. MarcoSandri, post as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `strptime` can be used to parse strings into dates.

You could do something like `strptime("19-SEP-2022", "%d-%b-%Y")`.

If your days are not zero-padded, then use `%e` instead of `%d`.

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete I want to add `parse_date_time` function from lubridate package. With no doubt, the preferred answer here is that of @Marco Sandri:

```
library(lubridate)

x <- "19-SEP-2022"

x <- parse_date_time(x, "dmy")
class(x)

[1] "2022-09-19 UTC"
> class(x)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

Answer (score 3):

A decade or so ago I starting writing the [anytime](https://cloud.r-project.org/package=anytime) package because of the firm belief that for *obvious* date(time) patterns we should not need to specify patterns, or learn grammars.

I still use it daily, and so do a bunch of other CRAN users.

```
> anytime::anydate("19-SEP-2022")
[1] "2022-09-19"
>
```

So here we do *exaxtly* what you ask for: supply the string, return a date object.